# What is wrong in regexp?

Tags: java, regex

I don't understand, why this regexp works not as I expect:

Regexp: `^<prefix>(.*?)(<optTag.*?>)?(.*?)<postfix>$`

Test: `<prefix>some chars<optTag value>some chars<postfix>`

Test result:

Group 1: Empty

Group 2: Empty

Group 3: `some chars<optTag value>some chars`

I would expect that group 2 = `<optTag value>`

Comment: Since group 2 and 3 are optional, group 1 or group 3 will consume it all depending on the input.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to use a regex to capture all possible cases unless the input space is very confined. For instance, if the first group can contain a prefix of `<optTag...` (without the closing angular bracket) then you will have nested patterns, and you cannot use a regex to match arbitrarily deep nesting.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a non-greedy wildcard preceding an optional capture group.  Use this instead:

```
^<prefix>([^<]*)(<optTag.*?>)?(.*?)<postfix>$
```

Comment: This will fail if the 1st group contains `<`.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a pain, but you could put a *block* assertion in those `(.*?)` groups.

`^<prefix>((?:(?!<optTag.*?>).)*?)(<optTag.*?>)?((?:(?!<optTag.*?>).)*?)<postfix>$`

https://regex101.com/r/6cQlkC/1

Expanded

```
 ^ 
 <prefix>
 (                             # (1 start)
      (?:
           (?! <optTag .*? > )
           . 
      )*?
 )                             # (1 end)
 ( <optTag .*? > )?            # (2)
 (                             # (3 start)
      (?:
           (?! <optTag .*? > )
           . 
      )*?
 )                             # (3 end)
 <postfix>
 $
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the word boundaries "\b" in your regular expression to get the required value in Group 2.

This ReGeX worked for me,

```
^<prefix>(.*?)(\b<optTag.*>\b)(.*?)<postfix>$
```

You can read more [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refwordboundaries.html).

Comment: This won't work if you drop `<optTag value>` from the test string.

Comment: Yes, of course, it won't. The op hasn't mentioned anything about varying "optTag" part of the entire "<optTag value>" part. Maybe he is looking only for the varying "value".

Comment: The OP's original regex has `(<optTag.*?>)?` clearly indicating the whole `<optTag value>` part is optional.